# Why react has View Layer only?

Tags: reactjs, view

I'm learning react recently. I don't understand why any online tutorial said that react has View Layer only. But I think react has Controller Layer only.

Can any one help me understanding how react has View Layer?

Comment: Can you explain what makes you think that React has a Controller layer only instead of View layer?

Comment: @lomse Because we have just a `.js` file, not `.html` file.

Comment: Well you seem to forget the fact that without an entry file which is an `.html` file, you won't be able to use your `.js` files from your react.js app

Comment: The `render` method outputs virtual DOM nodes, which get rendered into HTML by React - that's much more 'view' than it is 'controller'. That said, React is not an MVC library, and I find it's not really that helpful to try to map it to those concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If we think about a web app that utilizes React as utilizing a Model View Controller architecture then your tutorial makes sense. React acts as your view, but interfaces with your server. Your server acts as your controller, but interfaces with your database. Your database acts as your model.

A React application can be written completely in JavaScript files. In this case you would utilize [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) for your template structure and [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.11) for your styles.

React also gives you the ability to manipulate your DOM using JavaScript. It simplifies this by giving you [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) to work with, or [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Behind the scenes React uses a [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) and a process called [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) to make updates to only the components that require changes based on the JavaScript logic you implement. This makes React applications very efficient, and gives you a tremendous amount of control over your UI.

This is a very broad answer, but I think you need to spend some more time looking through the [docs](https://reactjs.org/) and watching more tutorials to understand the framework and how it fits into a web app's stack. Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction. It's a fantastic framework, so stick with it!